# Unable to deploy SharePoint project using VS2015

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, visual-studio-2015

I have a SharePoint server and I was able to deploy SharePoint 2010 project using VS 2010. After installing **VS 2015** and opening project by this version, it shows error as follows whenever I attempt to deploy-

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool':
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Could you help me to find the solution?

Comment: See this answer on SO: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72556/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-recycle-iis-application-pool-object-referen

Answer (score 0):

check your package solution 
if it is not exist .. try to find it from TFS and include it your project 
then restart your visual studio and deploy your solution again .